# Python window immediately not responding when testing programs?

Tags: python, user-interface, window

I'm currently going through a book and using PyScripter.  Everything has been fine until I got to the part where we started dealing with GUIs.

Basically when I start a program it immediately doesn't respond.  One part is making a program where the user clicks 3 points in the window, then it makes a triangle from connecting the points.  As soon as the triangle is made it stops responding.  So it waits for whatever the program was meant to do to be done then messes up.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
from graphics import *


def main():
    win = GraphWin("Draw a Triangle")
    win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0)
    message = Text(Point(5, 0.5), "Click on three points")
    message.draw(win)

    p1 = win.getMouse()
    p1.draw(win)
    p2 = win.getMouse()
    p2.draw(win)
    p3 = win.getMouse()
    p3.draw(win)

    triangle = Polygon(p1,p2,p3)
    triangle.setFill("peachpuff")
    triangle.setOutline("cyan")
    triangle.draw(win)

    message.setText("click anywhere to quit")
    win.getMouse()

main()
```

edit: updated with code. Like I said before the author of the book I'm reading made a toolkit from tk just to make it easy on beginners.

Comment: post some code if you want some help.

Comment: I assume the tutorial is [Hands On Python](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html). I ran your script in a console, and it works fine for me. If you're running it within PyScripter, the problem will probably be with that, rather than with the script itself.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it didn't 'mess up'. You just forgot to put win.close() after win.getMouse().

Answer (score 0):

almost guaranteed, the main event loop isn't running. How you do this depends on what GUI toolkit you are using, but doing it this way is problematic, since once you start the event loop, it will take over your console until it exits.

Probably the easiest way to handle this is to switch to IPython (http://ipython.org); once you start the console, you can just do

```
%gui wx
```

(or qt, or tk, or whatever gui toolkit you are using) and it will start the app loop in the background, allowing you to experiment.

this uses a python inputhook, and it's entirely possible to steal that code from IPython and use it in pyscripter, if you'd like. There may be a way to make them work together as well, not sure.

Comment: The toolkit is actually a small one put together by the books author.  I had to DL the file off his site.  I know looking through the file though that it comes from tk if that makes any difference.

Comment: @user2912641. See my comment on your question. This has got nothing to do with event loops - the `graphics` module you're using works fine as it is.